# Stop Android Studio from thinking Korean characters are typos

Tags: android-studio, ide, jetbrains-ide, spell-checking, cjk

I love keeping the "Problems" section of my IDE clean of errors, since besides Compile errors, Warnings and Hints often catch things for me.

[image: Example of 2 errors and 11 typos being highlighted in the "problems" section]

However I'm working on a multilingual project, and lots of files have Korean text in them. Android Studio thinks most most of this text is typos:

[image: Example of Android Studio thinking 결제하기 is a typo]

How can I disable the typo detection for Korean characters, or otherwise make Korean spellcheck properly work? Do I have to add every single word it thinks is a typo to my user/team dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing Korean dictionaries? 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spellchecking.html#dictionaries -- It's for IntelliJ IDEA but Android Studio should have the same or something similar; 2) https://hunspell.github.io/ --> https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/ko_KR